# Unity3d Input System multi key press

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to perform an action when I press 2 keys at the same time.

For example, I want to perform an action when I press both the mouse left click and the keyboard control keys at the same time. I could not find this feature in the "Add Binding" section.

Comment: you have to do that in script. for example get mouse click and when getting keyboard check if mouse is already pressed or not.

Comment: If it is about Ctrl you could probably use a [ButtonWithModifier](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Composites.ButtonWithOneModifier.html)  - in the editor via [Add Binding With One Modifier](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.8/manual/ActionBindings.html#one-modifier)

Comment: This worked thank you